# understand working of node server in term of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, cpu, ram

can someone help me to understand working of node server in term of memory ???

for example , i had a node server which on-boarding 20 rest web-services. consume 100mb in ideal state (no request are made)

on-boarding = web service available to consume by GUI OR we can say live/ready on node server to use

Q1. what if there is 40 on-boarding rest web-services , will it consume double memory ????

Q2 if there is a node server running on 4 core processor and with 512 ram ,

what happens when a request comes in node server , how it serve ?
And what if there is long queue of request how "Main Memory" & "processor cores" are use by node server ?

Comment: Your answers will vary depending on the set up you are using - my first suggestion would be to add specifics about how your server is written.

Comment: This really is too broad a question...

Comment: @robertklep that's why i added *in term of memory*

Comment: @LiamMacDonald i am asking about normal node server with express or any other framework , no load balancing, no multiple instance

Comment: How would we know what the memory requirements of _your_ webservices are? We have no clue what they do, if they depend on particular data/modules that need to be loaded into memory, etc. Hence, too broad.

Comment: @robertklep no they are only pipeline between GUI &  diff type of micro-services hosted either on same server or diff server

Comment: Start your app without any webservices and see what the amount of RAM that takes. Then add 10 webservices and check again. Then add another 10 webservices and check again. Etc.